# Visual Studio 2013 Community - is it a trial only?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I was looking at what version of VS 2013 to upgrade to, and discovered that my company qualified as sufficiently small enough to use the VS 2013 Community Edition. So on 19th March, I downloaded it, and took it for a test-drive, building a small app.

But tonight just when I really need to rebuild that app, it tells me my 30-day trial has expired. What 30-day trial? Where was that mentioned?

Any suggestions as to how to get around this? I have a demo to do within a matter of hours, and I'm beginning to panic...

Comment: I seem to recall that you need to login within VS with a MS Live account with VS-Community (unlike other editions there is no "retail" version without this requirement).

Comment: Thanks - in my haste, I misread the length of the trial period - 30 days not 90, so I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording is a bit bad, but once you sign in with a Microsoft Account you get a temporary license assigned that Visual Studio will try to refresh in the background. If the refresh fails for some reason, you will get this message and will need to click the "Check for an updated license" button on the Visual Studio Account screen.

[image]

This screenshot is from the Visual Studio 2015 RC, but the way the licensing works is the same:

[image]